# How to have the UI not blocked during long time operation?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a button, when user clicks it, it will update the entire UI(textview, graphs). The content of the UI comes from a SQLite database, I named the update function loading(). You could imagine, inside the loading(), there are lots of database operations and UI updates. 
When the size of the data getting bigger, the time for this loading() to be done is longer, so the button will stay in pressed state for a longer time.

I tried to use **asynctask** to deal with this situation so that a progressdialog comes out instead of the button freezed, but I cannot place the loading() method on the doinbackground() of **asynctask** because doinbackground() cannot touch the UI components that are declared from the onCreate() method of its activity.

I don't want to rewrite the loading() function.

Any other way to do so?? Please help, and if you could, please provide some examples, I appreciate that.

Comment: I dont understand why handlers are being down-voted but combination of handler and thread is at times a perfect option...

Comment: you've stated that your loading method requires the UI thread and actions you want to run off the UI thread.. sorry man, I know you don't want to rewrite it but your gonna have to.  Refactoring is fun, embrace it!

Comment: :( sad to heard this, but I think thats the only way as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run time-taking tasks on main application thread (a.k.a., UI thread) you will have unresponsive UI and eventually see the famous [Application Not Responding (ANR) dialog](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/images/anr.png).

Recommended way is to do these in AsyncTask and call `publishProgress()` in `doInBackground()`. Put your UI-updating logic in `onProgressUpdate()` of your `AsyncTask`. `onProgressUpdate()` will be automatically called on the main application thread after you call `publishProgress()`.

Comment: Ya, but my problem is that there are lots of UI updates in my loading() function. Because of simplicity, I don't really want to separate the loading function into 2 part, the calculating and the updating parts.

Comment: For example, there are many textview I need to update, and some of the textview are composed of few strings resulted from a calculation.

Comment: I think you have to separate it. I don't see any other solution. If there are some parts that you are sure won't take so  long you can keep them as it is. But the parts that take really long time has to go into `doInBackground()`

Comment: @user1701840 In order to keep your UI responsive, you pretty much *have* to separate the data loading code from the UI code.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I should really adapter this as well. Separate the UI and data loading

Answer (score 1):

In order to use AsyncTask in this instance you want to load the data in doInBackGround() and populate some kind of datastructure or model object with the results. Then return that as the result of doInBackground().

[onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) does run on the UI thread and can use the result to populate and update your components.

Answer (score 1):

Best option would in my opinion to use an AsyncTask to do this job. You can trigger progress update from loadInBackground to get some UI update when you need (call `publishProgress()` from the task background thread and the method `onProgressUpdate()` will get called on the UI thread).

Other option: have the job done in a separate thread or in a background service. Then from your UI, you can trigger a refresh every X milliseconds using a Handler.

Answer (score -1):

You can run things on the UI thread using `runOnUiThread(Runnable)`. You could also use a combination of `Thread` and `Handler`.

Comment: Someone want to explain to me why what I've stated is incorrect?

Answer (score -2):

I'm learning about `Handler`s currently and according to the documentation, they are the currently recommended way to access data because, for one thing, they do asynchronous loading for you. As you said, you can't access the UI components from another thread other than the UI thread. This means that whether you use a `Handler` or roll your own code with `AsyncTask` that you need to separate the code that updates the UI from the code that loads the data.